# This is my first kotlin code and i got error

Tags: android, kotlin

[Error that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72VWl.png)

To run code and want to know about why this error occurs

Error: Could not find or load main class eu.tutorials.kotlinbasics.Basics1Kt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eu.tutorials.kotlinbasics.Basics1Kt

Error: Could not find or load main class eu.tutorials.kotlinbasics.Basics1Kt

Comment: share your full code.